# How to get response from another site in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5.3

I want to create API in laravel which gives data return.
I want to get data from [this](http://mtaapi.herokuapp.com/stations) link
into my laravel controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by pulling in guzzle.  Try: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

```
$client = new Client(); 
$body = $client->get('mtaapi.herokuapp.com/stations')->getBody(); 
$obj = json_decode($body);
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thank you for accept my answer! I will give you first answer in Anders answer as a my comment! Thanks for seeing it and accept as a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a request to that url from your controller. This can be done by pulling in guzzle. Please see the readme of this repository: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: I already try it but it gives blank response.
   $client = new Client();
        $api_response = $client->get('mtaapi.herokuapp.com/stations');
//        $response = json_decode($api_response);
        dd($api_response);

Comment: @ParthSureliya Try like: `$client = new Client(); $body = $client->get('mtaapi.herokuapp.com/stations')->getBody();

$obj = json_decode($body);` Hope this helps you!

Comment: Try dumping $api_response->getBody(); Anything there?